# Search bulk datas within a JTable through JTextField without much delay

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield, rowfilter

I have created an application which searches the datas listed within a `JTable` while entering the required data in a `JTextField`.

The application works fine for small amount of datas, but in the case of bulk datas, searching seems to be a little delay.

Can anyone please tell me some solution/ suggestion/ other methods for this problem.

my code is given below.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
/**
 *
 * @author user55
 */
public class searching extends javax.swing.JFrame {
final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter;
    /**
     * Creates new form searching
     */
    public searching() {
        initComponents();
        int a=1,b=1000000,c=2000000;

           Object rows[][]=new Object[1000000][5];
  for(int i=0;i<1000000;i++)
  {
    rows[i][0]=a++;
    rows[i][1]=b++;
    rows[i][2]=c++;

  }
    String columns[] = { "Symbol", "Name", "Price" };
    TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, columns) {
      public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        Class returnValue;
        if ((column >= 0) && (column < getColumnCount())) {
          returnValue = getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        } else {
          returnValue = Object.class;
        }
        return returnValue;
      }
    };

    table1.setModel(model);
    sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
    table1.setRowSorter(sorter);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        filterText = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        table1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(table1);

        filterText.addInputMethodListener(new java.awt.event.InputMethodListener() {
            public void caretPositionChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
            }
            public void inputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
                filterTextInputMethodTextChanged(evt);
            }
        });
        filterText.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                filterTextKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 472, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(filterText)
                            .addGap(263, 263, 263))
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                    .addComponent(filterText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 221, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void filterTextInputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
        String text = filterText.getText();
        if (text.length() == 0) {
            sorter.setRowFilter(null);
        } else {
            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
        }
    }

    private void filterTextKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        String text = filterText.getText();
        if (text.length() == 0) {
            sorter.setRowFilter(null);
        } else {
            sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /*
         * Set the Nimbus look and feel
         */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /*
         * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
         * default look and feel. For details see
         * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(searching.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(searching.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(searching.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(searching.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /*
         * Create and display the form
         */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                new searching().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JTextField filterText;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private static final javax.swing.JTable table1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `RowFilter` searching inside whole `XxxTableModel`, for all rows, for every columns, for large model have to change `if (text.length() > 2) {` , still the first searching could be delayed, but reduced to searching for simgle char or combinations of two chars, this could be hard job for memory and processor too
- apply filtering for one of columns only
- not good idea to display bunch of datas never will be readable, this is job for `Sql interpeter` (Database)
- `getText` from `Document` (model for `JTextComponents`) as parameter for `RowFilter`

Comment: is there any other solutions

Comment: not, I think that not, because no one from programming languages is supposed to display 1Mio rows and columns too, this is job exclusivelly for database engines

Comment: how about searching and displaying the result through sql query

Answer (score 0):

If the UI is a separate thread and the call to the server is another thread. We can load the rows to the UI immediately when you get first 100 rows (say your call needs to get 1000 rows) from the server and update the UI with these rows, so the interaction with the user does not break because of the delay caused by the server call.

This is just an idea. Even I want to know how can this be effectively done.

In the above stated approach will there be any concurrency issues?

**P.S:** If you have already tried this please let me know the results.